# force_reply works in the address bar but does not work from code in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, telegram-bot, urlfetch

The telegram bot must send a message to the user with `force_reply` active.

Inserting the link in the address bar works; the bot sends the message and the `answer` function is already active. The same link, generated by the code in Google Apps Script, does not work; the bot does not send anything.

**Working link:** (I replaced the id of my bot and the ID of the chat with `BOT_TOKEN` and `CHAT_ID`)

```
https://api.telegram.org/BOT_TOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=CHAT_ID&text=force_replyTest&reply_markup={"force_reply":true}
```

**code to generate the link**

```js
var url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
function sendText(idChat,text) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + idChat + "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(text) + '&reply_markup={"force_reply":true}');
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
if(text == "/p"){
    sendText(idChat,"force_reply test");
  }
```

Comment: You need to encode the markup text too.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Work with this code
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + idChat + "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(text) + '&reply_markup=' + encodeURIComponent('{"force_reply":true}'));

Comment: You can add it as a answer in the answer box below.

Answer (score 1):

Thank to @TheMaster 
**Work with this code**

```js
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + idChat + "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(text) + '&reply_markup=' + encodeURIComponent('{"force_reply":true}'));
```